# Windows XP remote desktop window size is too small when physically switching to different machines

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

Main Workflow:

When you are physically on computer A (with a large resolution) and remote desktop (with the sub workflow) into computer B and then remote desktop again to computer C with a very large resolution on computer B.  Then physically go over to computer B (with a smaller resolution than computer A) and remote desktop (with the sub workflow) into computer C again, the Windows Remote Desktop client remembers the window size and can't reset it.  It's specific to the host you connect to.  When you physically log onto computer B and remote desktop using the sub workflow below, how do you correct this issue described after "NOTICE:"?

Sub-Workflow:

Windows Start menu > Run > type "mstsc" > click "Connect" on "Remote Desktop Connection" dialog > click "Connect" on "Do you trust this remote desktop connection?" > (NOTICE: remote machine maximized window is smaller than your local machine Windows operating system monitor screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new sub workflow should fix this issue:

Windows Start menu > Run > type "mstsc" > click "Options" on "Remote Desktop Connection" dialog to expand the options > click "Display" tab > check and uncheck the checkbox labeled "Use all my monitors for the remote desktop session" > click "Options" on "Remote Desktop Connection" dialog to collapse the options > click "Connect" on "Remote Desktop Connection" dialog > click "Connect" on "Do you trust this remote desktop connection?" > (NOTICE: remote machine maximized window is the same size as your local machine Windows operating system monitor screen)